# how to make imacros follow and read the frame number

Tags: imacros

I use iMacros to automatically upload some data over a specific site. to do so, I click on a button that open anew frame in the same page ; the problem is that the frame number is variable.
How to make iMacros follow and read the frame number ?

Answer (score 0):

This taks is a tricky one but can be solved .... not always.

What you want to do is extract the the HTML code of the whole div element or find a way to extract part of HTML that contains frame number somewhere. You do the rest with JS and match() search() methods with regex.

Comment: Unfortunately i can not find the frame number in the html code. can it be hidden

Comment: If the frame is like this FRAME F=1 then you can find it by recording. If a frame is like this FRAME NAME="sdbhwda23r53" then you have to look in html and find name="sdbhwda23r53" property somewhere.

Comment: it is like FRAME F=1 when recording but it is variable and i can not find it in the html code